# Set frame of UIButton to specific word in UILabel

Tags: iphone

I have a problem regarding to set UIButton frame.

```
     NSString *sample = @"Demo to set display view on label in iPhone";

     CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(55,9999);
     expectedLabelSize = [sample sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] 
                                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

     NSLog(@"%f",expectedLabelSize.height);


    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height)];
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.label.text = sample;
    [self.label sizeToFit];
```

So in below uibutton code how to set frame position of text so that only "iPhone" word is clickable?

```
    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.label.frame.origin.x, 
                               self.label.frame.origin.y+50, 
                               expectedLabelSize.width,
                               expectedLabelSize.height);
```

Comment: You want this button to automatically display over your label or under it?

Comment: i want to click only iPhone text of uilabel so any idea

Comment: Ah, I think you want the UIButton to be where the text "iPhone" is in the UILabel?  That is difficult with a multiple line label.  Better to put the text "iPhone" in the UIButton only and not put it in the UILabel.

Comment: No, he wants iPhone word to act as a hyperlink by setting button's frame to be right over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make just one word of a UILabel clickable as a hyperlink you would need to know exactly where the UILabel puts that word.  That is difficult (not impossible) especially with a multiple line label and especially if you allow resizing of the font to make the text fit.

Why not use a UIWebView and make it a hyperlink instead?  Or separate the text that is clickable and put that text into the UIButton by itself, like:

```
label.text = @"Demo to set display view on label in ";
button.titleLabel.text = @"iPhone";
```

Note: you should not checkmark this answer if your problem is not solved.

Comment: no its not work & can't get frame y of button please tell me any idea?

Comment: what part doesn't work? how does it fail?  Add the NSLog and see what it says (and tell us).

Comment: Actually i want to get frame of y of button and i used self.label.numberOfLines = 0 for multiple line of text in uilabel and CGSizeMake(55,9999) to set height of uilabel so please give me idea to set y frame of button

Comment: Try the NSLog, what did you get?  Maybe the y is too big and off screen?  Try the NSLog and see!

Comment: its returns buttonFrame = {{50, 100}, {55, 147}} so its click on all text but i want only click on iPhone text so please any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean "only click on iPhone text"  Please try to explain more in your question what is not working and what you want to do.

Comment: i want to add custom button over uilabel in iPhone text and click on that to navigate next view and when i edit my label text like iPhone hello world so its click on world text so please help me